# PHP Save selected options from Multiple Drop Downs to an Array

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, html-select

I have the following code:

```
<select id='rq1' class='business' name='q1'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<select id='rq2' class='business' name='q1'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<select id='rq3' class='business' name='q1'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NMQz8/

What I am trying to understand is if it is possible to save the responses from each of the `dropdowns` to an Array.  The reason for this is so that I can save the results into one column in the database as opposed to having a column for each dropdown response.  Does that make sense?

Is this possible, is it as straightforward as adding `[]` to the name and then `unserializing` them to `post` to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form method='post'>
    <select id='rq1' class='business' name='q1[]'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <select id='rq2' class='business' name='q1[]'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <select id='rq3' class='business' name='q1[]'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

When you submit the form, you will get data in Array.

Comment: Yes - that is correct, exactly.  So I treat the dropdowns in the same way as any other input method?