# How to make array of multiple drop-down menus

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, drop-down-menu

Hi can anyone give an example of how to make an array of multiple menus? I want to get inputs from different menus and insert in one field, just like the implode on checkboxes separated by ",".... i want to have something similar to that in menus. I need the array so that i could insert it to 1 db field.

here's what i got for checkboxes. how am i gonna apply one for select/menus?

```
<?php


  include ("dbinfo.php");

  if (isset($_POST['button']))
   {
     $implode = implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (orders) VALUES ('".$implode."')") ;
   }
?>

<?php

  if(isset($_POST['button']))
   {
      $implode = implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (name, address, contact_no, payment_option,  claim_option, orders) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['address']."',  '".$_POST['contactno']."', '".$_POST['pay_option']."', '".$_POST['claim_option']."',  '".$implode."')");
   }
?>
```

The selected checkboxes inserts to 'orders' field. i need drop-down menus to insert to a 'quantity' field.

[image]

**EDIT**
Updated with the image. assuming that there are menus all the way down until the last checkbox.

Comment: something like this
<select name="quantity">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

Comment: @MustafaMJalal how am i gonna apply that to make an array of the user's selections to store in a db field?

Comment: an array can be done even in html <select quantitiy="name" multiple>....

Comment: just add the multiple attribute

Comment: @MustafaMJalal yes but my problem is how to get the user's selections from the menus so that it can be inserted to a db field. similar to how implode works on checkboxes. let's say user selects number 2 from menu1. then 3 from menu2, and 4 from menu3. the output in the db should be 2,3,4

Comment: $_POST['quantity']
it depends on how you want the array to look like. but that will give you the multiple values that the user selected and u can either change using php since that what ur using and then insert into db

Comment: @MustafaMJalal can you answer with a complete example code? with a mysql insert..pretty please

Comment: can you go to a chat?

Comment: @MustafaMJalal i want to get inputs from different menus and insert in one field. can't chat i think bcause of low rep.

Answer (score -1):

assuming u only want one value from each select

```
<select "menu1" >
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
?>
<option value="<?=$x?>"><?=$x?></option
<?
}
?>
</select>
<select "menu2" >
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
?>
<option value="<?=$x?>"><?=$x?></option
<?
}
?>
</select>
<select "menu3" >
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
?>
<option value="<?=$x?>"><?=$x?></option
<?
}
?>
</select>
<?php
$quantity = $_POST['menu1'].",".$_POST['menu2'].",".$_POST['menu3'];
?>
```

---

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (quantity) VALUES ('$quantity')");
```

Comment: Updated post with the image. assuming that there are menus all the way down until the last checkbox.  Here's the problem, is it possible to have multiple menus and insert the selections to 1 field only. like from menu1,menu2..so on.

Comment: so u want all values into one field from multiple inputs
you do this
$selections = $quantity.", ".$implode.", ".$etc>>>

Comment: yeah..can you elaborate that? i want to get inputs from different menus and insert in one field. can't chat i think bcause of low rep.

Comment: you would make it easier for me if you tell me which menus u need to insert db and which field you want them in and how do you want them to be separated in order to recognized later and in what order you want them to be... explain more.

Comment: Okay.if I have 3 menus with select names of(menu1,menu2,menu3).each has a dropdown of numbers 1-10. If in menu1 I select #2, in menu2 I select #5,in menu3 I select #7, then after clicking submit button,it inserts to one field in the db named 'quantity'.so if i look in that field it should contain 2,5,7

Comment: It's giving an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\MCC\orderform.php on line 230, the very bottom.

Comment: no errors now..nut it's not inserting anything to the db. T__T

Comment: u missing this "}" some where in ur come i didnt write 230 lines btw

Comment: well i'm assuming u have a problem with ur code particularly in ur html form

Comment: bcause i'm using dreamweaver. i found this. similar problem to mine. but doesn't show how it gets the array and insert to the field. maybe you can edit?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672196/php-save-selected-options-from-multiple-drop-downs-to-an-array